# Cannot find my mistake in string escaping with backtick

Tags: javascript, string, escaping

My string without backticks works fine when I write as,

```
client.query("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM companiestable WHERE adminemail = 'givenMail@gmail.com')", 
  (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err.stack)
    } else {
     console.log(res.rows[0].exists);
    }
});
```

But when I try taking this e-mail as a parameter using backticks, it doesn't work. I can't find my mistake.

```
var givenmail = 'givenMail@gmail.com';

client.query(`SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM companiestable WHERE adminemail = ${givenmail});`, 
  (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err.stack)
    } else {
     console.log(res.rows[0].exists);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add quotes around your email in the template string. Without them, your string renders to this:

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM companiestable WHERE adminemail = givenMail@gmail.com;
```

What you need is quotes around the email, sql will yell at you otherwise. Here's what that look like in a template string:

```
`SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM companiestable WHERE adminemail = '${givenmail}');`
```

Notice the quotes around the injected value. It will now resolve to:

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM companiestable WHERE adminemail = 'givenMail@gmail.com';
```

And all should be peaceful once again in SQLand.

Comment: what if my value to be replaced has `'` in it?

Comment: Thanks! I'll never forget this.